# Return false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me why `return false` is not working? I just want to check if current is yellow. If it is yellow class don't do nothing (return false). The problem is when you click a button it runs its thing again but I want to avoid that.
Here's [the Fiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/3YLEg/).

```
/*INSIDE THIS CODE RETURN FALSE NOT WORKING!!*/
$('.yellowcontroll').click(function(){

    if($yellow.after('.current').length){
        $('.yellow').show();
        $('.slideswrapper:not(:animated)').animate({'marginLeft':'-=100'},1000,function(){
            $('.current').removeClass('current').hide();
            $('.yellow').addClass('current');
            $('.slideswrapper').css({'margin-left':'0px'});

            if($('.current').is($('.slideswrapper div:last'))){
                $('.blue,.green,.red').clone().insertAfter('.slideswrapper div:last');
            }

            if($('.current').is($('.red'))){
                $('.red').prevAll().remove(':not(.yellow)');
                $('.yellow').insertAfter($('.slideswrapper div:last'));
            }

            /*THIS IS NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED!!*/    
            if($('.current').is($('.yellow'))){
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a console.log() on the line where you expecting to return a false? Is it reaching that part of your code?

Comment: Please format your code before you post so that it would be lot easier for us to read and understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning false from the callback to your animation, not the event callback.

If what you are looking for is for nothing to happen when you click the second time then you could move the condition and return false to the front of the click callback:

```
$('.yellowcontroll').click(function(){

    /* MOVE THIS TO THE BEGINNING OF THE CLICK CALLBACK */    
    if($('.current').is($('.yellow'))){
        return false;
    }

    if($yellow.after('.current').length){
        $('.yellow').show();
        $('.slideswrapper:not(:animated)').animate({'marginLeft':'-=100'},1000,function(){
            $('.current').removeClass('current').hide();
            $('.yellow').addClass('current');
            $('.slideswrapper').css({'margin-left':'0px'});

            if($('.current').is($('.slideswrapper div:last'))){
                $('.blue,.green,.red').clone().insertAfter('.slideswrapper div:last');
            }

            if($('.current').is($('.red'))){
                $('.red').prevAll().remove(':not(.yellow)');
                $('.yellow').insertAfter($('.slideswrapper div:last'));
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do... I'll update with one possibility.

Comment: I've updated with one possible solution, but I can't be sure that this is what the intended behavior is...

Comment: THX!! Prestaul it just what I wanted:) So stupid of me to put my logic on the end...I am still learning so Thank You!!

Comment: No problem! Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your fiddle is a mess, but based on your question, it seems that you simply have your logic in the wrong place. Try placing your `return false` logic at the top of your click event:

```
$('.yellowcontroll').click(function(){
    if($('.current').is($('.yellow'))){
        return false;
    }
    ...
  });
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/3YLEg/4/) should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to put that code snippet in the beginning of the click handler:

http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/3YLEg/2/

```
$('.yellowcontroll').click(function(){
          /*THIS IS NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED!!*/    
          if($('.current').is($('.yellow'))){
                 return false;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the conditional false code to the beginning of the click handler like below and use `hasClass` like below.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/3YLEg/5/)

```
    if ($('.current').hasClass('yellow')) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('.current').is('.yellow')){
    return false;
}
```